# Extends an NPM module class with no typings from TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I wanted to experiment with [mobx-firebase-store](https://github.com/nyura123/mobx-firebase-store) in my TypeScript code. It has no typings but uses JavaScript classes.

I tried to convert this [ChatStore.js](https://github.com/nyura123/mobx-firebase-store/blob/master/examples/chat/src/ChatStore.js) code which imports the MobxFirebaseStore class:

```
import MobxFirebaseStore from 'mobx-firebase-store';
```

and later extends it:

```
export default class MessageStore extends MobxFirebaseStore {
```

Since there are no types, I tried using this trick to make the library declared as `any`

```
typings install mobx-firebase-store=common~any --save
```

then:

```
import * as MobxFirebaseStore from 'mobx-firebase-store';
```

but this line:

```
export default class MessageStore extends MobxFirebaseStore {
```

has the following errors:

```
TS2507:Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.
TS4020:Extends clause of exported class 'MessageStore' has or is using private name 'MobxFirebaseStore'.
```

What is the quickest and easiest way to get get past these errors and be able to extend to class in a similar way to what is being done here with Babel?

Comment: Not a proper solution, but you can always import something untyped:
const MobXFireBaseStore= require('mobx-firebase-store')

Comment: Thanks. Is there untyped in TypeScript? I believe `any` is the loosest type available. I had tried what you suggested and have used that method for other modules, but I believe it still gets typed as `any`. In this case it seems a constructor function is required and TypeScript's supposedly optional typing is not optional.